# How can I test an ajp worker (tomcat10, apache 2.4.6)?

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, mod-jk, ajp

I have a simple server setup:

1. Apache 2.4.6
2. JK Worker for talking with Tomcat, where a REST service is living
3. Tomcat 10

#### Virtual Host

In my virtual host file I have this configuration **(snippet in `<VirtualHost *:443>`)**:

```
<Directory "/var/www/frontends">
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine On

    # [...]
    RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api$ sdp-api/test/ [PT]
    RewriteRule co2avatar-app/sdp-api/(.*)$ sdp-api/$1 [PT]

    # anything else to index.html
    RewriteRule co2avatar-app/(.+) co2avatar-app/index.html [L]
</Directory>

# worker definition
JkMount /sdp-api/* ajp13_worker_prod
JkMount /sdp-api ajp13_worker_prod
```

#### Workers

```
# workers.properties -

# workers.tomcat_home=/opt/tomcat/latest/

#
# workers.java_home should point to your Java installation. Normally
# you should have a bin and lib directories beneath it.
#
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/

ps=/
worker.list=ajp13_worker_prod,ajp13_worker_test,ajp13_worker_tomcat10_test,ajp_worker_tomcat10_prod

#
#------ ajp13_worker WORKER DEFINITION ------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
worker.ajp13_worker_prod.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker_prod.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker_prod.type=ajp13

worker.ajp13_worker_test.port=8010
worker.ajp13_worker_test.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker_test.type=ajp13

worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_test.port=8020
worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_test.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_test.type=ajp13

worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod.port=8019
worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod.type=ajp13

# we do not use load balancing at all.
```

I should add that the *ajp13_worker_prod* worker points to a service in a Tomcat 9 instance, the *ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod* worker to a Tomcat 10 instance. But this works very fine for a different virtual host (which is effectively the test system).

Everything works fine until I change the lines

```
JkMount /sdp-api/* ajp13_worker_prod
JkMount /sdp-api ajp13_worker_prod
```

to

```
JkMount /sdp-api/* ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod
JkMount /sdp-api ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod
```

The services in Tomcat are working fine, I can reach them via `curl http://localhost:6085/[...]`. So the ports are open for usage from localhost.

But I cannot reach them *from outside*, via Apache. Here I am getting a *500* with `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

I scanned all possible error log files, but I cannot see problem, especially not in the Apache logs.

#### Is there any way to test an JK worker?

#### Is there any way to test the Tomcat Connector?

It looks like this in *server.xml*:
`<Connector port="8019" proxyName="co2avatar.org" proxyPort="80" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="false" />`. The HTTP connector works, but maybe not this one? There is a problem between Apache (the ajp worker) and Tomcat, but just firing request against Apache does not help yet.

###### (Beginner question:) Is it possible to restart the JK module only?

Here is an excerpt from Apache *error_log* (there is nothing in mod_jk.log):

```
[jk:warn] [pid 1286] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default /etc/httpd/logs/jk-runtime-status
[slotmem_shm:debug] [pid 1286] mod_slotmem_shm.c(448): AH02301: attach looking for /run/httpd/slotmem-shm-mod_heartmonitor.shm
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1286] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(181): AH02199: SSL not enabled on vhost h2862201.stratoserver.net:80, skipping SSL setup
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(239): AH02202: Init: Read server certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/cert.pem'
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(239): AH02202: Init: Read server certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/cert.pem'
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(239): AH02202: Init: Read server certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/fullchain.pem'
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(239): AH02202: Init: Read server certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/cert.pem'
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(239): AH02202: Init: Read server certificate from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/cert.pem'
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(391): AH00821: shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(407): AH00822: for 511912 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 88 indexes each
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(440): AH00824: shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(442): AH00825: subcache_num = 32
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(444): AH00826: subcache_size = 15992
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(446): AH00827: subcache_data_offset = 2128
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(448): AH00828: subcache_data_size = 13864
[socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1286] mod_socache_shmcb.c(450): AH00829: index_num = 88
[socache_shmcb:info] [pid 1286] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[ssl:info] [pid 1286] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_init.c(1502): Init: SSL server IP/port overlap: h2862201.stratoserver.net:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:57) vs. co2-avatar.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf:4)
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_init.c(1502): Init: SSL server IP/port overlap: gitlab.sustainable-data-platform.org:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitlab-le-ssl.conf:2) vs. co2-avatar.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf:4)
[ssl:debug] [pid 1286] ssl_engine_init.c(1502): Init: SSL server IP/port overlap: co2avatar.org:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/co2avatar.conf:66) vs. co2-avatar.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-le-ssl.conf:4)
[ssl:warn] [pid 1286] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[ssl:info] [pid 1286] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.6 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.6, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2k
[proxy:debug] [pid 1292] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1292] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1292] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1292 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1293] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1293] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1293] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1293 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1295] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1295] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1295] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1295 for (*)
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1286] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_jk/1.2.48 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_prefork:info] [pid 1286] AH00164: Server built: Nov 16 2020 16:18:20
[core:notice] [pid 1286] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_prefork:debug] [pid 1286] prefork.c(1005): AH00165: Accept mutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1294] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1294] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1294] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1294 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1296] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1296] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1296] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1296 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1378] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1378] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1378] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1378 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1408] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1408] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1408] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1408 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 1859] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 1859] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 1859] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 1859 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 15109] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 15109] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 15109] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 15109 for (*)
[proxy:debug] [pid 17029] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[proxy:debug] [pid 17029] proxy_util.c(1888): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[proxy:debug] [pid 17029] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 17029 for (*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is embarrasing, but I've used a wrong name in my workers list.

`ajp_worker_tomcat10_prod` instead of `ajp13_worker_tomcat10_prod`.

The interesting part is that there was no error message like *worker not found* or *worker has no config*. Just the weird message from Apache and nothing in *mod_jk.log* or Apache's *error.log*.

This might also be a configuration problem.